# Decryption of Text with jasypt not working

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am getting an issue where i am getting an exception while decrypting some  text with jasypt.I already install `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files` and the encryption works just fine.

Here is my sample code

```
PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
         int number_of_cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
         encryptor.setPoolSize(number_of_cores);
         encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256");
         encryptor.setPassword("stackoverflow");
         String plaintext = "This is a test";
         String encryptedtext = encryptor.encrypt(plaintext);
         String decryptedtext = encryptor.decrypt(encryptedtext);
         System.out.println(plaintext);
         System.out.println(encryptedtext);
         System.out.println(decryptedtext);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1055)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(PooledPBEStringEncryptor.java:498)
```